# Backbone fetch async timeout not taking effect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to do a fetch on a large backbone collection that involves some server side processing.

I tried setting timeout to 0 (for a infinite timeout) or to a large value:

```
aCollection.fetch({
    // ...
    timeout: 500000
});

// or:

aCollection.fetch({
    // ...
    timeout: 0
});
```

…but neither of them are taking effect; the `GET` query involved during the fetch operation times-out every 2 minutes.

Is this a browser timeout over-riding the fetch async options? is there any work around for this?

Comment: Did you consider that could be your server timing out?

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem too and it was due to node default timeout (I was using expressjs).
It's probably not the best solution but I changed the server timeout. 
this.server.timeout = 240000; (4minutes)

Comment: This (and handling the corresponding 408 on the client) is the correct solution.